C# Result Pattern - Flatten arrays
In our current project, we have a very simplified version of a Result object.  One of the things we are interested in adding to it is the ability to take multiple results containing an array of items and then combining them into a single result object containing all of the items from the other results.
The issue we are running into is when trying to make this generic through the IEnumerable<T> interface, we get an error stating Cannot convert Result<string[]> to Result<IEnumerable<string>>.
Below is a simple reproduction of the error.  I know I could just add a method to handle T[], but is that the only option?  I'm guessing this is something to do with covariance/contravariance, but I have never been good at knowing which is which and when to use what.
class Result
{
    public static Result<T> Create<T>(T value) => new Result<T>(value);
    public static Result<IEnumerable<T>> Flatten<T>(params Result<IEnumerable<T>>[] results)
    {
        return new Result<IEnumerable<T>>(results.SelectMany(x => x.Value));
    }
}

class Result<T>
{
    internal Result(T value) => Value = value;

    public T Value { get; internal set; }
}

var result1 = Result.Create<string[]>(["A", "B"]);
var result2 = Result.Create<string[]>(["C", "D"]);
var result3 = Result.Create<string[]>(["E", "F"]);

// Should create a result of ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
var result = Result.Flatten<string>(result1, result2, result3);


What's the point of Result<T>?

Covariance only works with interfaces, not concrete types. You'll need to define some covariant interface for your result objects and work with that.

It cannot be completely inferred by base class. You can get close using public static Result<IEnumerable<T>> Flatten<T, TA>(params Result<TA>[] results) where TA : IEnumerable<T> { return new Result<IEnumerable<T>>(results.SelectMany(x => x.Value)); } then when calling: var result = Result.Flatten<string, string[]>(result1, result2, result3);  Forgive the formatting but the question had been abruptly closed pointing to duplicates of duplicates. :)

is AI somehow involved in finding the links to duplicates one might wonder...

expanding on @JeffMercado interface IResult<out T> {     public T Value { get; } } and the method public static Result<IEnumerable<T>> Flatten<T>(params IResult<IEnumerable<T>>[] results) {         return new Result<IEnumerable<T>>(results.SelectMany(x => x.Value));     }

@StevePy too bad this was closed as a duplicate.  Your solution worked for what I needed.  Thank you.
